# LEFT JOIN, ORDER BY and pagination

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pagination

The elements of my list are not displayed in alphabetical order. This list is displayed page by page (pagination : page 1, page 2, page 3 ....).
I used `ORDER BY` but my request returns false results.

```
SELECT * FROM structure
  LEFT JOIN typologie
    ON structure.id_typologie = typologie.id_typologie 
  LEFT JOIN pays 
    ON structure.id_pays = pays.id
ORDER BY nom_contact ASC
```

Examples with the data:

zone attente Roissy
        AP-HP (Archives de)
        AP-HP bureau recherches
        Apprentis d'Auteuil MECS Saint-Jean Eudes
        APTIRA
        Caroline Chateau
        Château de la Villette
        Chivilo (Mme)
        CICR Genève
        CICR Kinshasa

Where is the problem?

Comment: Add sample data please.

Comment: Which table does nom_contact belongs to?

Comment: Just the query is usually not enough. We would like to have more information about your setup, like the definition of your tables. And I hope you manage the pagination in your query to get faster results?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. @jarlh : `nom_contact` is refered to the table `structure`. I used `structure.nom_contact` and I have same results.

Comment: Seems like you want a case insensitive order by. Try ORDER BY lower(nom_contact) ASC

Comment: @jarlh : I don't understand, what is the lower ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see your sorting is case sensitive. Change your `ORDER BY` to the following:

```
SELECT
    s.*
FROM
    structure s
    LEFT JOIN typologie t ON s.id_typologie = t.id_typologie 
    LEFT JOIN pays p ON s.id_pays = p.id
ORDER BY
    LOWER(s.nom_contact) ASC
```

That should fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you. I tried that but I don't have exactly right results.   As :                       "              La Commanderie   /  
  La nécropole de Noyers Saint Martin   /  
  Le Président du Souvenir Polonais en France  / 
  Les Auxilaires des Aveugles     /
  MAC GRAVY MICHELE  /
  Ministère Défense Internet  /
  PAF du Val d'Oise    / 
  PRO BUSQUEDA DE NINAS I  /
  SPRENE (MIE)  /
  CADA Nicolas Garnier Forum Réfugié "

Comment: Have you checked if your data is inserted correctly in the database? There could be a (hidden) character before the C of CADA Nicolas [...].

Comment: I think that the problem is resolved thank you so much :-)

Answer (score 0):

The ORDER BY clause of your query doesn't specify "nom_contact" of which table out of the three that is joined.

Comment: I tried that : `structure.nom_contact` and I have already the same results.